# Duplicate a folder on FTP server

Tags: c#, winforms, server, ftp

I'm creating a winform app and i'm trying to copy a folder and its content to the same directory on the FTP server (duplicate it) so for example let's say the FTP server folder now look like:

```
FTP://.../Main/temp/a.txt
FTP://.../Main/temp/b.txt
```

After the duplication of 'temp' folder 'Main' folder should look like:

```
FTP://.../Main/temp/a.txt
FTP://.../Main/temp/b.txt
FTP://.../Main/NewDir/a.txt
FTP://.../Main/NewDir/b.txt
```

I wonder what is the best way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: The "best" way is to do it with some C# programming.

Comment: A more serious answer: "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Being more kind is a more serious answer.. dumb

Comment: I really don't understand why you don't search through Google or SO. Then [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808815/107625) should have been easily discoverable.

Comment: SO there's no standard way of doing this, because of this i did not found anything on google BEFORE i posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

[You Can use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311975/c-sharp-upload-whole-directory-using-ftp)

First download in temp dir the folder and upload (follow the link) by changing the name. It can be a solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there is no faster solution? i think that downloading whole folder then uploading it costs too much.

Comment: You can use WinSCP .NET dll here https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library
I don't use it but i think you will find what you want in the doc

Comment: Thanks! i'll check it