# Folder uploader with c#

Tags: c#, html

I have to upload a folder that folder contains files to the server with the help of c#. If we have any plug ins or any other ways, please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Either you have to zip the files together or add the files as a Mime attachments to the body (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315024/4860100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315024/4860100)

Comment: But first, i need to select folder to upload. so need folder uploader option from UI